# Creating a new line for an output using the same variable?

Tags: javascript, html

Very much a newbie here and wanting a bit of guidance.

I'm trying to create a project where you bind a key to start a timer then show an output in the results box. However i'm facing an issue where I need to create a new line if the user releases the bound button to start a new timer, however I can't find a way to start the timer again. Bear in mind within the time, a user could press the bound key over a hundred times, I don't want to manually create new lines and timer's.

My thoughts are creating a a random token, then on release, it creates a break, if the next line doesn't match this token it begins again.

Edit:So you can see, the value is based on the 2 variables, and even when I hold down the specific button again, it just adds to the current smallTime. I know this is how it's currently build, but i'm trying to get it to reset and go to the next line dynamically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
  <head>

      <textarea class="code_input" name="allInputs" id="textareaCode" wrap="logical" rows="10"    cols="50" readonly="true"> </textarea>


      <script type="text/javascript">


        var shortSeconds = 0;
        var shortmillisec = 0;    


        function buttonPressed(e) {
          key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLocaleLowerCase()
      //alert (key)
          keyInput = e.keyCode

          if (withinTime == true && key == bind) {
            shortDisplay()
            shortTimerFunction();
          }
        }

        function shortDisplay() {
          if (shortmillisec >= 9) {
            shortmillisec = 0
            shortSeconds += 1
          }
          else
            shortmillisec += 1
        }


        function startstoptimerShort() {
          if (shortTimer > 0) {
            clearTimeout(shortTimer);
            shortTimer = 0;
          } else {
            withinTime = true
            shortTimerFunction()
          }
        }

        function shortTimerFunction() {
          smallTime = shortSeconds + "." + shortmillisec;
          shortTimer = setTimeout("shortTimerFunction()", 100);

          //need to work out what line to put the output on
          allInputs = document.getElementById('textareaCode')
          allInputs.value = (textbox3.value) + (":  " + smallTime) + '\n';
        } 

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest boiling your problem down to its essence and updating your question. You will have better luck without so much code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's my first day. Script is now edited.

Comment: And I suggest making an jsfiddle : ( http://jsfiddle.net/ ) :) It will make people answer even faster :)